# Using hierarchical entity as an action filter in LUIS

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, azure-language-understanding

I added an action to an intent.

**That action requires a parameter of type Fruit**.

Fruit is a hierarchical entity [banana, orange, apple].

I expected when I passed in an apple then it would trigger that action but it doesn't and I'm not sure why?

[image]

The intent is successfully matched but not the action:

```
{
  "query": "eat an apple",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "Eat",
    "score": 0.999997139,
    "actions": [
      {
        "triggered": false,
        "name": "Eat",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "FruitType",
            "type": "Fruit",
            "required": true,
            "value": null
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "Eat",
      "score": 0.999997139,
      "actions": [
        {
          "triggered": false,
          "name": "Eat",
          "parameters": [
            {
              "name": "FruitType",
              "type": "Fruit",
              "required": true,
              "value": null
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "intent": "None",
      "score": 0.04917145
    }
  ],
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "apple",
      "type": "Fruit::apple",
      "startIndex": 7,
      "endIndex": 11,
      "score": 0.916528642
    }
  ],
  "dialog": {
    "prompt": "FruitType missing",
    "parameterName": "FruitType",
    "parameterType": "Fruit",
    "contextId": "1b4333e4-4a00-4714-8041-4b9bacb1feb4",
    "status": "Question"
  }
}
```

Instead I have to specifically use parameter type of fruit::apple - which to me defeats the magic of the intent.

[image]

```
{
  "query": "eat an apple",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "Eat",
    "score": 0.999997139,
    "actions": [
      {
        "triggered": true,
        "name": "Eat",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "FruitType",
            "type": "Fruit::apple",
            "required": true,
            "value": [
              {
                "entity": "apple",
                "type": "Fruit::apple",
                "resolution": {}
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "Eat",
      "score": 0.999997139,
      "actions": [
        {
          "triggered": true,
          "name": "Eat",
          "parameters": [
            {
              "name": "FruitType",
              "type": "Fruit::apple",
              "required": true,
              "value": [
                {
                  "entity": "apple",
                  "type": "Fruit::apple",
                  "resolution": {}
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "intent": "None",
      "score": 0.04917145
    }
  ],
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "apple",
      "type": "Fruit::apple",
      "startIndex": 7,
      "endIndex": 11,
      "score": 0.916528642,
      "resolution": {}
    }
  ],
  "dialog": {
    "contextId": "93839bc8-a26a-436b-90c4-842891344ac6",
    "status": "Finished"
  }
}
```

**Essentially this limitation means I could not have an EatFruit intent.**

Instead I would have to have EatApple, EatBanana, EatOrange intents which is not really what I thought this was all about.

Am I doing it wrong or is this just how it's done? And if this is how it's done then whats the point of a hierarchical entity?

I may as well just use a plain old entity and then I can pass it anything [apple, banana, orange] but then it will also match on [pear] which I don't want.

Comment: Have you added enough examples for the Fruit hierarchical entity?

Comment: How would I know that? As I say it matches the intent so I would assume so.

Comment: Actually the entity type is a different model from the intent. So make sure that it matches the utterances  you want to capture first, if not, you need to provide more examples

Comment: I don't understand. In both json dumps it says the entity is a Fruit::apple with a score of 91.6%. Is that not matching on entity type?